# How does Reactor hybrid push/pull model work?

Tags: java, project-reactor

Let's consider the Reactor [An hybrid push/pull model](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_an_hybrid_pushpull_model) example at the bottom used with this simple subscriber:

```
flux.subscribe(s -> log.debug("received: {}", s));
```

would receive each emission twice: one from `onMessage()` while the other from `sink.onRequest()`.

Is this the desired behaviour or should be something else?

```
Flux<String> bridge = Flux.create(sink -> {
    myMessageProcessor.register(
      new MyMessageListener<String>() {

        public void onMessage(List<String> messages) {
          for(String s : messages) {
            sink.next(s); 
          }
        }
    });
    sink.onRequest(n -> {
        List<String> messages = myMessageProcessor.getHistory(n); 
        for(String s : message) {
           sink.next(s); 
        }
    });
});
```

I also consider that `onMessage()` would run on a different thread than `main`.